# How to create different functions for different text messages in telebot?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I'm using telebot and want to create several functions based on text inputs.
But it doesn't work. Bot takes only the first function.
Is it possible to create for example different function for greeting and data request so on?
I know I can do similar things usings command but I need to use text instead. Also because it's like conversation not process I don't want to use register_next_step_handler. Is thera a way with message_handler functions?
thank you in advance!

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def greetings(message):
    if message.text.lower()=='hello':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Hello {message.from_user.first_name}")
    elif message.text.lower()=="bye":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Good Bye {message.from_user.first_name}")
    else:
        pass

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def requests(message):
    if message.text.lower()=='data':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{message.from_user.first_name} which data do you want?")
    elif message.text.lower()=="forecast":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{message.from_user.first_name} we have only historic data")
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I think you can use the func input for the message handler.

```
# Create a function that checks the message and sends answer to message handler
def check_function(message):
    if message.text.lower() == "hello":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Hello {message.from_user.first_name}")
        return True
    elif message.text.lower() == "bye":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Good Bye {message.from_user.first_name}")
        return True
    elif message.text.lower() == "forecast":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{message.from_user.first_name} we have only historic data")
        return True
    elif message.text.lower() == 'data':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{message.from_user.first_name} which data do you want?")
        return True
    else:
        pass

# Message handler using func
@bot.message_handler(func=check_function)
# Create a fake function that does nothing cause you need something after the handler that isn't polling.
def foo(message):
    pass


bot.polling()
```